# I have written a sed script and want to include a command that will pull a long string of numbers, all being 0-9, and could possibly have letters

Tags: bash, sed

I have a non-pixelized pdf that I have converted into a `.tdt`. I am trying to pull some specific information from it to put into a table in html.  I am wanting to pull the "name", which is followed by spaces and then the number I want to capture.  There are two other names with space in between that precede the name I want to capture. The number could look like this, 125000009856472333 or 125LLLLLVI4673302 or 125689*990000. I have written these two lines:

```
s="$s; s/^.*(Name)  +(*.)$/\2/p" |sed -rn "$s" input.files.txt
```

and

```
s="$s; s/^.*  +*.(Name)  +*(0-9a-zA-z)$/\2/p" |sed -rn "$s" input.files.txt
```

I receive nothing

```
s="$s; s/^Name *([^)]+)/Name\t([^)]+)/p" |sed -rn "$s" input.files.txt
```

output was**:** Name  ([^)]+) instead of Invoice Number and the number we want to
capture.

I am wanting to use this to process 21 files that I have concatenated.  The result should be two columns, one with name and the other column with different combinations of letters, numbers and possibly some special characters.

Comment: Your question would be a lot easier to understand with example input and output.

Comment: can you try to escape `\2` as `\\2` and add it into the 2nd pattern? I feel that bash is swallowing one slash before sed sees it

Comment: We can't tell what you want to do by reading code that doesn't do what you want to do and it's not at all clear what the code you posted was supposed to do nor why you're trying to populate a variable to contain a sed script and  then calling sed with that variable instead of simply calling sed with a script. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Comment: I see you tagged your question with [`s`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/s) - does the `s` statistical programming language REALLY have something to do with your question or did you add that tag because you named one of your variables `s`? If the former please explain the connection, if the latter please remove the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Without a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and/or more details I can't be sure, but to capture the Name and the numbers/letters after the whitespace perhaps you want something like:

```
sed -n 's/.*\(Name\)[[:space:]]\{1,\}\([[:alnum:]]\{1,\}\)/\1\t\2/p' file
```

You can also add special characters to `[[:alnum:]]` if you need to, e.g. `[[:alnum:]+-,.]`, or change `[[:alnum:]]` to `[[:alnum:][:punct:]]` if you want to capture all printable characters except space.

Does that answer your question?